# I am getting poor TTS using num2words as input for pico2wave

Tags: python

In a Python script, `num2words` seems to generate unicode text. When this is used as input to `pico2wave`, a 'u' is prepended to the text. How can `num2words` generate ascii so `pico2wave` will work properly?

Printing the output for example:

```
var1 = 12  

numb = numb2words(var1)  

print(numb)
```

Output: `u'twelve'`

When used as input to pico, "uhtwelve" is spoken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library unicodedata to convert your unicode to ascii.

We will use the "NFKD" form of unicodedata.normalize for the conversion. According to [unicodata documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html):

> there are two additional normal forms based on compatibility
>   equivalence. In Unicode, certain characters are supported which
>   normally would be unified with other characters. For example, U+2160
>   (ROMAN NUMERAL ONE) is really the same thing as U+0049 (LATIN CAPITAL
>   LETTER I). However, it is supported in Unicode for compatibility with
>   existing character sets (e.g. gb2312).
>
> The normal form KD (NFKD) will apply the compatibility decomposition,
>   i.e. replace all compatibility characters with their equivalents.

Hence the solution will be:

```
import unicodedata

var1 = 12

numb = numb2words(var1)
numb = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', numb).encode('ascii','ignore')

print(numb)
```

Comment: That doesn't work - the printed u is becuase it's unicode. There is no actual u in the variable, but it is treated as if is.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. I have edited the solution to fit your requirement

Comment: i have altered my code, and it's working now. instead of assigning the output of num2words to a variable and then using it in the pico parameters, i place the function directly in the parms passed to pico - that seems to get rid of the unicode situation.

Comment: that is a strange solution... did you try my solution?

Comment: Oddly, i am not able to duplicate my original problem, but your solutions looks promising. Thanks